# get gps coordinates offline

Tags: gps, offline

Is there a way to get currect geographical coordinates using android gps while being offline (e.g. lost in the mountains) without additional applications?

Comment: Sure: Enable GPS. Might take a little to get a fix, but should work without any network support at all.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there isn't a way to do it without additional applications but [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eclipsim.gpsstatus2) or [this one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=es.prodevelop.gvsig.mini&hl=en_GB) seem to do what you need it to.